# Menu not adding the right items

Tags: menus, woocommerce-offtopic

I created a menu that includes all the different product categories. Yet the menu displays:

- Blog
- Cart
- Account
- Shop
- etc..

It does not display the product categories, just those titles. I have no plugins except for [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/).

The code I used to add the menu is within the `functions.php`:

```
    function register_my_menus() {
       register_nav_menus(
       array(  
         'header_navigation' => __( 'nav' )
        )
      );
    } 
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

And in my `index.php`:

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'nav', 
    'container' => false, 
    'menu_class' => 'nav', 
));
?>
```

And through the admin panel I created a menu and called it `nav`. Then added the product categories.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your menu location as `header_navigation`. Use the menu location slug `header_navigation` in your call to `wp_nav_menu()`, not the description (`nav`):

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'header_navigation', 
    'container' => false, 
    'menu_class' => 'nav', 
));
```